# Exoplayer 2 и M3U8

Tags: android

Почему-то в своем приложении не смог воспроизвести поток типа m3u8, используя ExoPlayer 2. Подскажите, пожалуйста, может нужно дополнить код чем-то. MP3 нормально воспроизводит.

Вот код:

```
bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
TrackSelection.Factory streamSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveVideoTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(streamSelectionFactory);

player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector, new DefaultLoadControl());

// Measures bandwidth during playback. Can be null if not required.
DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
// Produces DataSource instances through which media data is loaded.
DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "yourApplicationName"), bandwidthMeter);
// Produces Extractor instances for parsing the media data.
ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
// This is the MediaSource representing the media to be played.
Uri streamUri = Uri.parse("http://live2.mediacdn.ru/sr1/radiogrozny/playlist.m3u8");
MediaSource streamSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(streamUri, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
// Prepare the player with the source.
player.prepare(streamSource);
player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

А вот то что выкидывается в лог:

```
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error.
com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaSource$UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available extractors (MatroskaExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, AdtsExtractor, Ac3Extractor, TsExtractor, FlvExtractor, OggExtractor, PsExtractor, WavExtractor) could read the stream.
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaPeriod$ExtractorHolder.selectExtractor(ExtractorMediaPeriod.java:699)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ExtractorMediaPeriod.java:623)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:295)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Что удивительно, ExoPlayer 1.5.8 воспроизводит m3u8.